# Is there a way to use the Google Maps TimeZone API from within the google.maps object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So in order to look for places you can use the Google Places API you can either use the API like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

or you could use the functionality inside the google.maps object like this

```
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.gmap);

  var that = this;

  if ( data.search.length <= 0 ) {
    request['types'] = data.types;
    service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
      that.markPlaces(results, status);
      that.gmap.setZoom(14);
    });
  } else {
    request['query'] = data.search;
    service.textSearch(request, function(results, status) {
      that.markPlaces(results, status);
      that.gmap.setZoom(14);
    });
  }
```

I was wondering if there is a built in object inside the `google.maps` object to use the instead of the API, just like the Places Service

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=API_KEY
```

The reason I'm asking is because IE8 is giving me a hard time with the ajax request (cross-domain) and I'd like to not rely on the XDomain object built in IE8

Comment: Send the request through a proxy on your server.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. The server is behind a firewall with no outgoing access to the internet. That's how I found out about `google.maps.places.PlaceService` in the first place